# (Spring) perform authorization with a DB table

Tags: mysql, spring, authentication

Yo, I am learning Spring.
In this new episode I would like to perform a login with DB.

So I created my SQL schema in MySqlWorkbench called "demodb", in this schema I have a table with 3 columns (Username, Pass, Auth)

The problem:
When I run my app and the login form appear even if I enter the right username and password with `Auth` column setted to "ROLE_USER" I cannot proceed.

After 3 try got error 401.

This is my `SecConfig.xml`

```
<sec:http auto-config="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <sec:http-basic/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
   <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDeatilsService"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myUserDeatilsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Ha

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Security you should define queries for Users and User Roles table.

See spring security docs for examle: [spring security doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-schema.html)

See also nice guide from Mkyong: [Spring Security form login using database](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/)